# Cannot open files in Downloads folder by clicking

Tags: macos, security, privacy

I recently migrated to a new mac using time machine. In the new mac, using 13.3.1 (22E261), I cannot open recently downloaded PDFs files in the Downloads folder. I need to open preview, and then select the PDF file. If I then close the file, I can open it by clicking. I guess is a security/privacy setting, but don't know how to change it.

Is there a way to restore the more direct way?

Comment: If you move the PDFs to another location, do they open from the Finder?

Comment: @benwiggy sometimes it does. Not sure when. I was not able to find a correlation

Comment: What app did you download them with? Safari, or something else?

Comment: @benwiggy Firefox.

Comment: Maybe test from Safari - it could be a Firefox issue? Make sure you're on the latest version.